# JNI SIGSEGV on SetDoubleArrayRegion in Thread

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

I am trying to call the following function from Java in a separate thread:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray

JNICALL
Java_de_bastian_sip2labor_MainActivity_filtertest(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jdoubleArray ka)
{
  double b_y1[121];
  int k;
  int j;
  static const double dv0[12] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.65 };

  jdouble *sig1;
  sig1=env->GetDoubleArrayElements(ka, 0);


  memset(&b_y1[0], 0, 121U * sizeof(double));
  for (k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
    for (j = k; j + 1 < 122; j++) {
     b_y1[j] += dv0[k] * sig1[j - k];
    }
  }

  env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(ka,sig1,JNI_ABORT);

  jdoubleArray output = env->NewDoubleArray( sizeof(b_y1) );
  env->SetDoubleArrayRegion( output, 0, sizeof(b_y1), &b_y1[0] );

  return output;
}
```

It is a filter which takes an array of doubles, modifies it, and returns it to java as the function result.

The app crashes on startup, I assume because of this line:

```
env->SetDoubleArrayRegion( output, 0, sizeof(b_y1), &b_y1[0] );
```

The first time I encountered this issue it occured after onPause() was called while the seperate thread with the call might have still been running. Therefore I think it has something to do with the lifecycle. Is it possible to somehow check if the activity is still active before trying to execute SetDoubleArrayRegion() or is it maybe another problem?

The strange thing is that the code was working fine until recently:
I started to read a file which is then used as the input for the filter. The first time the app is launched after a fresh install, it asks the user to grant file reading permissions. If the user grants them the app works fine and you can see filter output. From then on, when the app is started, the permission to read the file is already granted and the app tries to immediatelty start the filter and it crashes then.

Simple logcat output:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x89fa2830 in tid 8498 (Thread-5)
```

Detailed Logcat output:

```
#00 pc 0001a21e  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+46)
    #01 pc 004394a6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI23SetPrimitiveArrayRegionIP13_jdoubleArraydNS_6mirror14PrimitiveArrayIdEEEEvP7_JNIEnvT_iiPKT0_+1174)
    #02 pc 0041e87c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI20SetDoubleArrayRegionEP7_JNIEnvP13_jdoubleArrayiiPKd+44)
    #03 pc 0015c9d2  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI23SetPrimitiveArrayRegionEPKcNS_9Primitive4TypeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jarrayiiPKv+1474)
    #04 pc 00144665  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI20SetDoubleArrayRegionEP7_JNIEnvP13_jdoubleArrayiiPKd+53)
    #05 pc 00000e10  /data/app/de.bastian.sip2labor-FUb-fvR-Nwyxco0g-cmxow==/lib/x86/libsip2labor-lib.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20SetDoubleArrayRegionEP13_jdoubleArrayiiPKd+160)
    #06 pc 00000fcc  /data/app/de.bastian.sip2labor-FUb-fvR-Nwyxco0g-cmxow==/lib/x86/libsip2labor-lib.so (Java_de_bastian_sip2labor_MainActivity_filtertest+428)
    #07 pc 0063ec67  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+71)
    #08 pc 000049d3  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading past the end of your `b_y1` array when doing the call to `env->SetDoubleArrayRegion( output, 0, sizeof(b_y1), &b_y1[0] );`

```
sizeof(b_y1)
```

Returns the size of the array in bytes, *not* the number of elements. On my platform this is 968, but your `b_y1` only has 121 elements so this is undefined behaviour.

You can fix this by passing `121` (the *actual* size of the array) instead of `sizeof(b_y1)`. But since you're using C++, I'd suggest switching over to using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), since it keeps the size for you, and generally has a more high-level api:

```
std::array<double, 121> b_y1;
int k;
int j;
static const double dv0[12] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.65 };

jdouble *sig1;
sig1 = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(ka, 0);

b_y1.fill(0);
for (k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
    for (j = k; j + 1 < 122; j++) {
        b_y1[j] += dv0[k] * sig1[j - k];
    }
}

env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(ka, sig1, JNI_ABORT);

jdoubleArray output = env->NewDoubleArray(b_y1.size());
env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(output, 0, b_y1.size(), b_y1.data());

return output;
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your fast answer, it works like a charm now!